# ME864LL/A Logic Board swap from MF839LL/A

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

I've got a late 2013 retina MBP and I want to know if I can swap the logic board from a 2015 MF839LL/A retina MBP. Can anyone tell me if this board will fit? They look like they're the same size and both MBPs share the A1502 designation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a definitive no. The board from the 2015 MBP does not fit the late 2013 MBP 13".